# Clone element input javascript with null value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
            var num     = $('.clonedInput').length;
            var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

            var newElem = $('#input' + num).cloneNode(true).attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

            newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
            $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');

            if (newNum == 5)
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });
```

I cloned the textbox but the code does not work, how do I resolve this?

Comment: what is the element with class 'clonedInput'? What do you need its length for?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is the least useful description a person can use.  What part of it doesn't work? What results do you get?  Check your Javascript console -- are there any error messages? If so, what is the *exact* message and which line that you posted matches that message?\

Comment: People give a non-native english speaking newbie a break. Stefan: obviously to add one more than there are currently

Comment: @mplungjan -- Non-native to English isn't the issue.  To get help in any language, the OP would have to describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: Sure but op is completely new so give him time before closing. I believe i understood the issue so others might too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);
```

As per [documentFragment.cloneNode(true) doesn't clone jQuery data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831414/documentfragment-clonenodetrue-doesnt-clone-jquery-data)

Update: perhaps you want to clone num-1 since num is the new field that does not yet exist